# Set file path on FTPClient

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

i'm new to java programming and am using Apache commons net ftp to upload text files to my ftp server.

however, it seems that i can only upload the files on the same directory as my program .. when i set the file path to something like that : "C:\Users\Packard\Documents\ProjectsJava\FugeLessons\outputFile.txt" , it throws no errors, but when i check the ftp, there is nothing, like it has not been uploaded .

here is the code i'm using :

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ftp{
    private final String host = "ftp.address.com";
    private final String user = "user";
    private final String pass = "pass";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ftp client = new ftp();
        client.FtpUpload("C:\\Users\\Packard\\Documents\\ProjectsJava\\FugeLessons\\outputFile.txt");
    }

    public String FtpUpload(String filename){
       FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
       FileInputStream fis = null;

       try {
           client.connect(this.host);
           client.login(this.user, this.pass);
           fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
           client.storeFile(filename, fis);
           client.logout();
           System.out.println("File " + filename + "\t uploaded successfully!");
       } catch(IOException e){
           error error = new error();
           error.setVisible(true);
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           try {
               if ( fis != null) {
                   fis.close();
               }
               client.disconnect();
           } catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       String ret = "success";
       return ret;
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong ?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ftpClient method getReplyString() to get the error message. Below code can help.

```
boolean isSendSucces = ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, input );
if( isSendSuccess )
{
    System.out.println("Sent File: " + fileName);                   
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Problem is sending File: " + ftpClient.getReplyString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesnt upload the file . i got only the ftp output message : 221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.

Comment: Check the user permission on the folder on which you are trying to upload the file.